# Why is this Javascript Snake Game Touch Event logic not working?

Tags: javascript, logic, 2d-games

For some odd reason the snake is sometimes moving right when it's suppose to go left and up when it is suppose to go down. Sometimes the movements are correct but other times they are wrong. Help would be appreciated.

```
function handleStart(evt){

   evt.preventDefault();
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   var touches = evt.changedTouches;
   var touchPos = [touches[0].pageX, touches[0].pageY]

   if(snake.direction === 'up' || snake.direction === 'down')
   {
     if(touchPos[0] < snake.x)
     {
       snake.direction = 'left'
     }
     else
     {
       snake.direction = 'right'
     }
   }

  else if(snake.direction === 'left' || snake.direction === 'right')
  {
     if(touchPos[1] < snake.y)
     {
       snake.direction = 'up'
     }
     else
     {
       snake.direction = 'down'
     }
  }

  else if(game.over)
  {
     game.start();
  }

}
```

Comment: If that code is listening to touchmove events there will be problems as it will switch between up,down and then left,right movements for each touchmove event. One way to solve the problem is to get the angle from the snakes head to the touch position and then move in the direction up,down,left or right depending on which is the closest to calculated angle

Comment: @Blindman67 Oops, I forgot to add that I was using touchstart, sorry.

Comment: If its touch start then the problem is not in the code you provided above but somewhere else. If you can provide more code that will help get you an answer as currently there is not enough information to solve.